# Yii2 получить весь список массива переданный через render

Tags: php, yii2

В контроллере передается render

```
return $this->renderView('create', [
  'model' => $model,
  'modelForm' => $modelForm,
  'params' => $params,
  ....
]);
```

как весь список этих массивов получить в самом view?

Например для я у меня есть CRUD, и там есть файл create.php, который вызывается из контроллера, а потом в этом файле вызывается _form.php. Чтобы при смене названия модели мне вручную не менять в нескольких местах я хочу получить весь список массивов

Comment: включите фантазию, создайте класс MyViewModel, заполните нужными атрибутами (model, modelForm, params, etc...)  и гоняйте её по вьюхам

Comment: Мало кода. Нужны примеры того, что есть и то, что надо получить. Тут либо некорректная архитектура применяется, либо я не совсем понял вопрос. Но у меня еще ни разу не возникало подобных ситуаций, чтобы получать весь список массива.

Comment: Это не так критично для меня, просто для упрощения работы нужно было. Спасибо за ответ. я понял